# ServiceCollection instance is not created

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET 5 Web-API with VS2015 Ultimate Preview. I'm trying to create an instance of `Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection` class.

I have this code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ServiceCollection oServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        oServiceCollection
            .AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer();
        IServiceProvider oServiceProvider = oServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

but the instance `oServiceCollection` doesn't appear neither Locals window nor Auto window. It seems `oServiceCollection` instance creation is not working.

What is the best approach to create an instance of `ServiceCollection` class in this type of ASP.NET Web project?.

Comment: You're creating it upon application startup, when are you trying to access it?

Comment: Yes @haim770. I trying to access it in ConfigureServices method in Startup class.

Comment: Two questions: 1. What exactly are you trying to do? In most cases you don't create the service collection, one is provided for you (that's the `services` parameter). And 2. the code might be optimized out. Check that you're running in Debug mode and not in Release mode.

Comment: Adding one more point to what Eilon said: if you need to create a new `ServiceCollection`, make sure `ConfigureServices` returns `IServiceCollection` not `void`. Otherwise, use the `services` object